# How do you create an Effect in Purescript directly via its type constructor?

Tags: purescript

Is it possible to use the `Effect` constructor directly? e.g. `foo = Effect "howdy!"`

It *seems* like this should be possible. It appears to be a type constructor.

```
:kind Effect
Type -> Type
```

However, if I try to construct it an error gets thrown

```
Effect 1234
Unknown data constructor Effect
```

I can only create one 'indirectly' with `pure`

```
myeffect :: Effect Int 
myeffect = pure 123
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It lacks a data constructor. Try `data MyEffect a` vs `data MyEffect a = MyEffect a` for `MyEffect 3`. Only that `Effect` is defined as `foreign import data Effect :: Type -> Type` (https://github.com/purescript/purescript-effect/blob/master/src/Effect.purs#L13).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is not how types work

The signature `Effect :: Type -> Type` means that if you take the word `Effect` and attach a type to the right of it, the result of that will be another type. So:

```
Effect :: Type -> Type
Int :: Type
Effect Int :: Type
```

This does not say anything about creating *values* of type `Effect`. That is:

```
Effect Int :: Type

x :: Effect Int
x = Effect 42  -- not necessarily allowed
```

For many types this happens to work just fine, for example:

```
Maybe Int :: Type

x :: Maybe Int
x = Just 42   -- perfectly valid
```

But it doesn't have to. It all depends on how the type is defined. For example:

```
data MyType a = Foo

MyType :: Type -> Type
MyType Int :: Type
x = Foo 42   -- not allowed
y = Foo      -- allowed
```

Note that I use the word `Foo` to construct values of `MyType`, not the word `MyType`. This is because they are different things. `MyType` is the name of the type, and `Foo` is the name of a *constructor* - which is a function that can construct (hence the name) values of a type. Other examples of *constructors* are `Just` and `Nothing` - both used to construct values of type `Maybe`.

A constructor may have the same number of parameters as the type itself, or it can have fewer parameters, or more. For example:

```
data Type1 a = Ctor1 a
data Type2 a = Ctor2
data Type3 a = Ctor3 a a

x :: Type1 Int
x = Ctor1 42 

y :: Type2 Int
y = Ctor2

z :: Type3 Int
z = Ctor3 42 84
```

So, to summarize: depending on how the type is defined, you may or may not use the name of the type to create values of that type, the way you're trying to do with `Effect`.

(also, some types may have *multiple* constructors, e.g. `data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing`, but this is already taking too long)

But all of this doesn't even apply to `Effect`, because...

### This is not how `Effect` works

`Effect` does not have any constructors at all. There is absolutely no way to directly create values of this type, regardless of parameters.

This is because `Effect` is *magic*. A value of type `Effect Int` is definitely *NOT* a sort of "box" that contains an `Int` inside. No-no-no.

Instead, a value of type `Effect Int` is a *program*, which, when executed, will eventually produce an `Int`. You can't look inside it, you can't take it apart, the only thing you can do with it is execute it.

And how do you execute it? Easy! You return it from your `main` function!

No, seriously, that's the only way to execute an `Effect`. (well, ok, there's also `unsafePerformEffect`, and then you can do it with FFI, but those are hacks for the initiated, don't go there)

The normal way you execute an effect is to return if from your `main` function, and the runtime will take care of it. Boom!

Another way to look at it is that your whole program is one big (or small) `Effect`. That's your program.

Another thing you can do with effect is to combine it with another effect using operator `>>=` (or its evil twin `=<<`). For example:

```
x = pure 40
y = x >>= \a -> a + 2

z = pure 42
```

Here, `y` and `z` are equivalent programs: both, when executed, will produce number `42`.

And this is the way you write programs in PureScript: you start with built-in ("magic") functions that produce effects, such as `cwd` or `readLine` or whatever, and then compose those effects with others via `>>=` or `=<<` or the `do` notation (which is syntactic sugar for `>>=`). Then, the resulting big effect, constructed out of many small ones, you return from your `main` function - and voila, you got yourself a program!